# How to fire an exception when a duplicated value is tried to be inserted (without constraints usage)?

Tags: oracle

In an interview somebody asked me how to create a table that throws an exception when a duplicated value is tried to be inserted in a column, but no constraints should be used. This is in Oracle.

It might be a dumb question, but how do you achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what constraints are for...?

Comment: I agree, and I told him so but he asked me again how to do it. He didn't tell me the answer or what he was expecting.

Comment: Maybe it's a trick question. I'd just say I refuse to even think about it without justification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unique index on the table would enforce the uniqueness requirement without creating a constraint (creating a unique constraint will create an index if no suitable index exists already).  But that's quite possibly against the spirit of the question-- it's a somewhat subtle distinction.  I would hope that an interviewer probing whether a candidate understood that distinction would choose a better way than this to ask the question.  Asking "What is the difference between a unique constraint and a unique index" would be a useful conversation starter that didn't require the candidate to try to parse the intention behind a silly request.

It would be a really poor idea but you could write a trigger on the table that, either with appropriate serialization or by ignoring the possibility that multiple sessions might be inserting duplicate rows at the same time, would throw an exception if there were duplicate rows.  This would be a really poor use of a trigger but it could be done.

You could also create a materialized view that refreshed on commit and included only keys that occurred multiple times and then use a constraint on the materialized view or a trigger on the materialized view to throw an exception.  That would probably be even less reasonable than the trigger solution (I could argue that the materialized view with a constraint might be preferrable to the trigger) but it could be made to work.

Comment: It makes sense, @Justin-Cave. I was thinking of the trigger as well but it wouldn't have any performance like gain or even worse: It would cause the trigger to behave badly and cause errors and even a mutating table as a result. Thanks.